# Error while compiling linphone android when run make

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, linphone

I am compiling linphone for andriod . I downloaded the files through git

```
$ sudo apt-get install git
$ sudo git clone git://git.linphone.org/linphone-android.git –recursive
```

before that i added the path in ~/.bashrc file

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/gnome/Desktop/android/android-sdk-linux/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/gnome/Desktop/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/gnome/Desktop/android/android-ndk-r10d
export ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT=true
```

I also added the path in eclipse too by going to  (Window -> Preferences).

when i run the make command in the directory where all the linphone files are it keep giving me this error:

```
Could not find ndk-build. Please install android NDK.
Could not find android. Please install android SDK.
Makefile:73: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop.
```

Its been 4 days that i am facing this problem :(.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set up ANDROID_HOME env.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/gnome/Desktop/android/android-sdk-linux
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the folder with your system files(in kali sana, its by clicking the "computer" icon once a folder is open)
2. Now, trace out the path to your NDK and SDK. Most likely it will be seen through the directory named root.
3. Then correct the path in your `~/.bashrc` file. an example path might be /root/Desktop/...                    (I used kali linux 2.0 for this)